# Ruby Rails getting 404 Not found on HTTP GET Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, get, restful-authentication

I am trying my hand at Ruby Rails. I am trying to render my Database in JSON Format. For some reason whenever I send a GET request from Postman I keep getting a routing error. When I type in "rails routes", I get proper routes. Image of which is defined below.
Code for my route.db is given below and screenshot of the error. I would be grateful if someone could guide me on this.

Code for routes.db

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

 namespace 'api' do
  namespace 'v1' do
   resources :questions
  end
 end
end
```

Code for Controller

```
module Api
 module V1
  class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
   def index
    questions = Question.order('created_at DESC');
    render json: {status: 'SUCCESS', message:' Loaded Questions', data: questions}, status: :ok
   end
  end
 end
end
```

[image: Image of Error I am getting]

Comment: Is `QuestionsController` in api/v1/ folder?

Comment: you could paste the actual response JSON instead of the image.

Comment: I believe the `QuestionsController` is in the wrong directory. it should be in the `app/controllers/api/v1/` directory

Answer (score 0):

I used your code, no errors happen. My code is

config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  namespace 'api' do
    namespace 'v1' do
      resources :questions
    end
  end
end
```

app/controllers/api/v1/questions_controller.rb

```
module Api
  module V1
    class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
      def index
        #questions = Question.order('created_at DESC');
        render json: {status: 'SUCCESS', message:' Loaded Questions', data: 'data'}, status: :ok
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I think you may get your paths wrong.

Comment: Thats exactly what I have. But my file name is QuestionController. I just started learning ruby, could the file name be the problem The location of the file is the same as you said. 
config/routes.rb, and app/controllers/api/v1/QuestionsController.rb. I am sending a request to http://localhost:3000/api/v1/questions

Comment: @paddy Rails is a convention-over-configuration framework. Filename is preferably lower case. Here is some great [docs] http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action)

Comment: Thanks. Any chance you could suggest me any fixes for my code?  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QojnRc7SS9o This is the guy I was following. Tried to use my own thing that I wanted to code. I did it without checking with PHPAdmin though. Could it be an issue with my database?

Comment: I finally got it omg. Not sure what was wrong. Just did it from the start. Thanks everyone above. I think it was a matter of restarting my Postman. Just need to make a error handling thing now (To throw an error if its out of range)